# Input for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to search for how to do the inputs that shows the labels when a new word is inserted and the space is pressed,

like the one that let us insert the tags when creating a new answer in this fantastic website

But I don’t know the exact name and i’m not finding anithing usefull, how this type of input styling is called?

Comment: I’ve often referred to them as tokens or tags. Material UI has a [Chip](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/) component that I’ve seen used for the sort of input you’re talking about.

Comment: ^
https://material-ui.com/components/chips/

Comment: Thanks guys, that’s right what I meant, fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mostly seen this referred to as a 'tag input'.

You can find quite a few by googling that, but here's a couple of examples:

- [A React component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input)
- [A bootstrap plugin](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)